# Mac OS X: My wifi asks me for a password if I change networks in mid session, but not at login time?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

just a slightly irritating problem:

I have two wifi networks in my home, and both have their WPA keys stored in the keychain. However if I am connected to one, but need to change to the other in mid-session, it asks me for the WPA key. Irritating because keys are quite long and cumbersome.

It doesn't do this at login time: always selects the last network I was using (or tried to use), so the keychain clearly knows the keys.

How can I get this behaviour also when I change networks in mid-session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prompting for an administrator password is a preference (but I guess that's not what you see when being asked for the WPA key?):

- Go to System Preferences, Network
- Select your AirPort network
- Click button Advanced
- See the option "Require administrator password to: Change networks"

[image: Advanced AirPort preferences]

As you commented that you already have that option disabled, maybe OS X has forgotten the password for Keychain Access? Check the following then:

- Go to Utilities, Keychain Access
- Open its preferences, pane First Aid
- Consider enabling "Keep login keychain unlocked"?

[image: Keychain Access preferences]

(As an aside: see [MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/) to switch automatically!)

Comment: Actually that option was already unchecked, Arjan.

Comment: It might be prompting for Keychain access then?

Comment: Thanks for your help,Arjan. Unfortunately my panel looks exactly like yours!!

I'll play around with this and if I fix it I will post.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem problem -- network A -- to which I was able to connect anytime without entering password and B that was asking for password all the time. The only solution was to turn the airport off and then back on.

The answer was in the Keychain Access. I realized that A has 2 keychain records, in keychain *login* and *system* while B only in *system*.

I had some problems creating *login* keychain as it was disappearing again but in the end I have both of them even on the B network and all works as expected. The *login* keychain should allow access to *AirPort* and *SystemUIServer*.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I synchronised login and system passwords and then problem solved. I can add also, that this problem probably related to network password change. I had different (old and new) passwords stored on system/login keychain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it might be the AirPort admin setting:

1. Go to the "Network" panel in the System Preferences App.
2. Select AirPort on the left.
3. Click on the (Advanced...) button
4. Disable "Require Administrator Password to control AirPort˜

Comment: looks like my panels are different from those on Arjan's answer - I'm running Mac OS X 10.5.8